# changing the default username and password provided by netbeans and using the username -password combination I mention in the tomcat-users.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans

I launch *Tomcat* from netbeans. Though I edited the `tomcat-users.xml` file of tomcat but the username-password combination isn't accepted.Netbeans has it's own.

[image]

Is there any way I can change the default username and passowrd provided by netbeans or is there a way I can use the username and password I mention in `tomcat-users.xml` ?

*(whenever I overwrite the password or username,it is set to initial when I restart the IDE or next time I check)*

Is there any netbeans configuration file that I need to change ?

Answer (score 0):

The NetBeans tomcat username is stored in file ‘.nbattr’ with path like ‘your_home_folder.netbeans\7.1.1\config\J2EE\InstalledServers’ (`<attr name="username" stringvalue="tomcat"/>`).

The password is stored in as encrypted value in file ‘win32.properties’ with path like ‘your_home_folder.netbeans\7.1.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\keyring’.

If NetBeans does not save this values you should check write permission. But I think that the better is to correct ‘C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\conf\tomcat-users.xml’ (in your case). First you have to add the next line:

`</tomcat-users> tag: <user username="ide" password="...." roles="manager-script"/>`